# How to run JavaScript on each letter entered in a search/text box field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML

```html
<form id="project-filter" class="aui ajs-dirty-warning-exempt">
  <div class="project-filter-item">
    <input type="text" id="project-filter-text" placeholder="Contains text..." class="version-filter-  text text" value="">
  </div>
</form>
```

This is a search box (text) field on the page. 
I have a JS function that runs every time the page is loaded. The content of a page is like a table (headings and table data). However, the JS function doesn't run properly when something is entered in the Search box. 
(Only the heading are executed, and the script doesn't run in the table body)

So I want the JS function to run every time a letter is entered.

For that I have tried to do the following, but its not working.

```js
AJS.$('#project-filter-text').on('input', function() {
  // Call my JS function.
  setTimeout(removeProjectTypes, 0005);
  return true;
});
```

And this:

```js
AJS.$('#text').keyup(function(event) {
  if(AJS.$('#text').val() == true) {       
    // Call my JS function here
  }
});
```

Any suggestions on what should I do?

Comment: remove the AJS before the jquery identifier, that would be a good place to start.

Comment: use keyup event instead

Comment: What is this AJS library ?

Comment: `if(AJS.$('#text').val() == true) {` I doubt this will ever be _true_. Also you're using the the type attribute as identifier `#`.

Comment: AJS is Atlassian's JavaScript namespacing. e.g. AJS.$ is their reference to jQuery

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `keyup` event.

```html
<form id="project-filter" class="aui ajs-dirty-warning-exempt">
  <div class="project-filter-item">
    <input type="text" id="project-filter-text" placeholder="Contains text..." class="version-filter-  text text" value="">
  </div>
</form>


$('#project-filter').on('keyup', function() {
console.log('This will run each time :)');
});
```

Try that :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
<input type="text" id="project-filter-text" placeholder="Contains text..." class="version-filter-  text text" value="" onkeyup="myFunc()">


function myFunc()
{
 alert('ok')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onkeyup`:

```
<form id="project-filter" class="aui ajs-dirty-warning-exempt">
  <div class="project-filter-item">
    <input type="text" id="project-filter-text" placeholder="Contains text..." class="version-filter-  text text" value="" onkeyup=search()>
  </div>
</form>
```

And add your function into the js file:

```
function search() {
   console.log('run');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what ajs is, but with jquery you can use on method to wait for events

```
$('#project-filter-tex').on('keyup',function(){
    // do something
});
```

sometimes i had the problem too, that `jQuery.keyup()` did not work. don't ask me why not.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#project-filter-text').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which !== 0) {
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
    //Logic here
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="project-filter" class="aui ajs-dirty-warning-exempt">
  <div class="project-filter-item">
    <input type="text" id="project-filter-text" placeholder="Contains text..." class="version-filter-  text text" value="">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you need something which triggeres every time a letter is entered, try `oninput`:

```html
<textarea oninput="console.log(this.value)"></textarea>
```

`keyup` doesn't quite work. For example, try this MCVE:

```html
<textarea onkeyup="console.log(this.value)"></textarea>
```

It works fine, if you just tap each key. But press and hold and you'll hit the issue: This triggers once *per time the key is released*, not per letter entered.